# Add satellite track to WebGLEarth map (with e.g. Leafletjs or Cesiumjs)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cesiumjs

I have made a map with a lot of clickable markers (with popups) in WebGLEarth (http://www.webglearth.org/api) and I would like to have three satellite tracks around my globe. It is important that you clearly see that it is a satellite hovering somewhere (where doesn't really matter and it doesn't have to move). So, something like https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML.html&label=Showcases

However, WebGLEarth does not include a tool to do this. Adding a polygon won't work (guess it's a bug) and lines are not included yet. Also changing the marker into another icon does not work as there is only one standard marker (as far as I know). There is a request to make webglearth a proper leafletjs plugin, but of course, I would like to make my map now.

Someone has an idea on how to do this? Maybe a hint on how to combine WebGLEarth with Cesiumjs or Leafletjs ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the end goal?  Satellites don't "hover" (except maybe GEOs but they're far away).  The CZML example you link to has clickable markers, what needs to be different for your use case?

Comment: Hover as in that it has to be clear that the satellite is not stationary as all other markers in my map are. So I have both clickable stationary markers and I want some satellites. In my opinion the possibilities were getting another icon to indicate it's not a "normal" marker (which is not possible) or drawing a track around the earth with a (possibly moving) marker on the track somewhere (not possible). However, this morning I made a short straight polygon with at one end a marker, which indicates that the marker is moving. Not the nicest way but it comes close. So it's sort of solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a core Cesium developer.

WebGLEarth is simply a light wrapper around Cesium to mimic a subset of the Leaflet API. It's maintained by an independent third-party and not officially supported by anyone from the Cesium or Leaflet teams. My recommendation would be to drop WebGLEarth and switch to using Cesium directly (or Leaflet, but I assume you want 3D).  Anything you are currently doing with WebGLEarth should be easy to port to the native Cesium API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into Cesium a bit better.